# Best practice creating joomla module with multiple layouts

Tags: php, joomla

I am currently writing a joomla module showing the weather report on a touristic Information website. The weather data is updated twice a day in an XML file. 
The website should show the current temperature always in the header. But there is a menu item leading to a more detailed weather report which gets its data from the same XML file.
I started writing a module that has two layout files in the tmpl folder: the small basic one for the header and the detailed view.
You can choose the layout as usual in the backend.

Here is my simple question: 
As this is the first time i am doing this, I was just wondering if this is considered good or bad practice (at first I wanted to write two separate modules for this).

Just one point made me think of two seperate modules: 95% of the time, the website shows only the small view, which would use a lot smaller helper.php with less functions and so if I would write an separate module for that. Would that probably even speed up the page...?

What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You're right. I was just hoping that someone would stop me, in case this thing would not work for some reason I don't see at the moment. Thanks anyway.